# how to install and getting start with webrtc on windows server

Tags: webrtc

Hi could anyone to tell me how to install depot tools.I went through documentation and trying to install the webrtc in windows,I installed visual studio 2010 and some related stuff given in documentation still i am in confusion and many questions like why visual studio is required? are we have write code in visual studio?It acts like IDE for webrtc?

If not please tell me where we have to place our project in local file system and how to implement my first demo application..I found a video published by google demonstrating about webrtc in that they wrote code in a html file so is html file itself enough to develop.?

Though i have done a sample application in a html file still i am getting blank page and in console i am getting as UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION near navigator.webkitGetUserMedia() please help me out to know more about webrtc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you start by watching the excellent videos about WebRTC from [Justin Uberti](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E8C8ouiXHHk) and  [Cullen Jennings](http://vimeo.com/47682405), and then (shameless self promotion) get to grips with the code and examples in [Getting Started With WebRTC](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/) on HTML5 Rocks.

[webrtc.org](http://webrtc.org) is the home of the WebRTC project -- lots of resources and demos there.

Answer (score 2):

Just last month we released an open source project aimed to get developers into WebRTC fast and easy.

http://www.easyrtc.com/

It includes a cross-platform server kit which will run in Windows. Working demos are included.

Answer (score 1):

I just built the webrtc solution using VS2010 by following [this](http://www.webrtc.org/reference/getting-started/) web pages instructions and NOT using cygwin. I had but one issue which to resolve required the manual copying of two files into the correct folder, you will know which two files should you see the names of these files and read the error, you will then know the expected location when the build fails.

Ultimately you will get a peerconnection_server.exe and a peerconnection_client.exe by way of sample. I was able to modify them easily.

Hope this helps. Be sure to install the prerequisites and follow the instructions to the letter.

Comment: It crashed for me, has this happened to you? I have built them fairly easily (tried x64 and x86 with no luck)

Comment: Is there a trusted source to get the already built binaries for windows?

Answer (score 0):

As a clarification, the webrtc C++ library is one implementation you can use for the protocol.  Another is using the webrtc implementation in a (very) modern web browser, such as Firefox or Chrome.  Then, you'll just need HTML + JS, as per the articles in HTML5 Rocks.

Comment: Just wanted to note the OP is over 10 months old.

Comment: Isn't chrome using the WebRTC C++ library?